# How to change the button text in the SQL in a PHP code?

Tags: php, sql, conditional-formatting

The following is my code:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pm_categories WHERE parent_id = 512 ORDER BY tag desc"); ?>
```

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
 <a class="button button-blue plus20 category" href="https://www.parvizshahbazi.com/ganj_videos/app/listvideos.php?range=<?php  echo $row['tag']; ?>"><?php  echo str_replace("-", " - ", $row['tag']); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the result:

[The buttons have numbers 1-100,101-200 and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tgQ7.png)

I was wondering how I can have 801-1000 instead of 801-900. I know that the digits are created from the while loop. Is there anyway to manually create the 801-1000 button?

I tried to manipulate the chart numbers in SQL, yet if 801-900 is manually changed to 801-1000, it gives an error. Because they are in the category of 801-900. What I want is just 801-1000 on the button for 801-1000.

Here is my SQL 'pm_config':

[pm_config list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO46i.png)

In sum, this is what I want in the end (it is photo-shopped):

[What I desire to have in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phDX6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could, in your 'while' loop, create a specific rule, like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // if your loop is treating the 801-900 tag, then just change it to 801-1000
    if($row['tag'] == '801-900') { $row['tag'] = '801-1000'; }

    echo '<a class="button button-blue plus20 category" href="https://www.parvizshahbazi.com/ganj_videos/app/listvideos.php?range=' . $row['tag'] . '">' . str_replace("-", " - ", $row['tag']) . '</a>';
}
```